# Careers.SO should allow time-based search filtering

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Searching by proximity, offered relocation, and remote possibilities are a good start.

But there should also be a way to filter-out entries based on when they were listed (i.e., last day, last week, only before two weeks ago, etc.).

Comment: Is there a reason you would want information from a filter that you couldn't get by sorting the listings by recency?

Comment: @JonChan - yes: and I outlined that in the OP, "last day, last week, only before two weeks ago, etc". Why wade-through listings I don't want to look at to find the ones I do?